How can i solve the error "TypeError: this __dict__ descriptor does not support '_DictWrapper' objects" in tf_agents?
I wrote a reinforcement learning algorithm using tf_agents, complete with a custom environment and network. The observation from the environment is a dictionary (I tried creating the environment both in gym and with PyEnvironment from tf_agents). The observation (in gym) looks like this:
        Dict({
            'char1': Dict({
                'char3': Box(shape=(1, 5), 
                               dtype=np.int32,
                               low=0,
                               high=self.tokenizer.vocab_size - 1),
                                            
                'char4': Box(shape=(10, 100), 
                              dtype=np.int32,
                              low=0,
                              high=self.tokenizer.vocab_size - 1),

                'char5': Box(shape=(10, 512), 
                                 dtype=np.int32,
                                 low=0,
                                 high=self.tokenizer.vocab_size - 1)
            }),
            'char2': Box(shape=(50, 7), 
                          dtype=np.float32,
                          low=-np.inf,
                          high=np.inf)
        })

I tested the environment, and it works fine. I also tested the network, and it produces the correct results when called with the observations provided by the environment. I successfully created the agent and other components.
The error occurs when I try to run the DynamicStepDriver:
File "c:\Users\giorg\OneDrive\Desktop\Trader Bot\train.py", line 74, in <module>
    collect_driver.run()
  File "C:\Users\giorg\OneDrive\Desktop\Trader Bot\venv\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\traceback_utils.py", line 153, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "C:\Users\giorg\AppData\Local\Temp\__autograph_generated_file81_1_3mv.py", line 80, in tf__run
    ag__.for_stmt(ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(range), (ag__.ld(self)._steps,), None, fscope), None, loop_body_2, get_state_2, set_state_2, ('policy_state', 'time_step'), {'iterate_names': '_'})
  File "C:\Users\giorg\AppData\Local\Temp\__autograph_generated_file81_1_3mv.py", line 78, in loop_body_2
    time_step, policy_state = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(tf).while_loop, (ag__.ld(condition), ag__.ld(body)), dict(loop_vars=[ag__.ld(time_step), ag__.ld(policy_state)]), fscope)
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\giorg\OneDrive\Desktop\Trader Bot\venv\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\core\function\trace_type\trace_type_builder.py", line 170, in from_value
    return default_types.Tuple(*(from_value(c, context) for c in value))
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\giorg\OneDrive\Desktop\Trader Bot\venv\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\core\function\trace_type\trace_type_builder.py", line 170, in <genexpr>
    return default_types.Tuple(*(from_value(c, context) for c in value))
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\giorg\OneDrive\Desktop\Trader Bot\venv\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\core\function\trace_type\trace_type_builder.py", line 168, in from_value
    named_tuple_type, tuple(from_value(c, context) for c in value))
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\giorg\OneDrive\Desktop\Trader Bot\venv\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\core\function\trace_type\trace_type_builder.py", line 168, in <genexpr>
    named_tuple_type, tuple(from_value(c, context) for c in value))
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\giorg\OneDrive\Desktop\Trader Bot\venv\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\core\function\trace_type\trace_type_builder.py", line 175, in from_value
    {k: from_value(value[k], context) for k in value}, mapping_type)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\giorg\OneDrive\Desktop\Trader Bot\venv\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\core\function\trace_type\trace_type_builder.py", line 175, in <dictcomp>
    {k: from_value(value[k], context) for k in value}, mapping_type)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\giorg\OneDrive\Desktop\Trader Bot\venv\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\core\function\trace_type\trace_type_builder.py", line 144, in from_value
    elif isinstance(value, trace.SupportsTracingProtocol):
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\giorg\OneDrive\Desktop\Trader Bot\venv\Lib\site-packages\typing_extensions.py", line 647, in __instancecheck__
    val = inspect.getattr_static(instance, attr)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\giorg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\inspect.py", line 1830, in getattr_static
    instance_result = _check_instance(obj, attr)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\giorg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\inspect.py", line 1777, in _check_instance
    instance_dict = object.__getattribute__(obj, "__dict__")
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: in user code:

    File "c:\Users\giorg\OneDrive\Desktop\Trader Bot\Driver.py", line 61, in run  *
        time_step, policy_state = tf.while_loop(
    File "C:\Users\giorg\OneDrive\Desktop\Trader Bot\venv\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\core\function\trace_type\trace_type_builder.py", line 
170, in from_value
        return default_types.Tuple(*(from_value(c, context) for c in value))
    File "C:\Users\giorg\OneDrive\Desktop\Trader Bot\venv\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\core\function\trace_type\trace_type_builder.py", line 
170, in <genexpr>
        return default_types.Tuple(*(from_value(c, context) for c in value))
    File "C:\Users\giorg\OneDrive\Desktop\Trader Bot\venv\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\core\function\trace_type\trace_type_builder.py", line 
168, in from_value
        named_tuple_type, tuple(from_value(c, context) for c in value))
    File "C:\Users\giorg\OneDrive\Desktop\Trader Bot\venv\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\core\function\trace_type\trace_type_builder.py", line 
168, in <genexpr>
        named_tuple_type, tuple(from_value(c, context) for c in value))
    File "C:\Users\giorg\OneDrive\Desktop\Trader Bot\venv\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\core\function\trace_type\trace_type_builder.py", line 
175, in from_value
        {k: from_value(value[k], context) for k in value}, mapping_type)
    File "C:\Users\giorg\OneDrive\Desktop\Trader Bot\venv\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\core\function\trace_type\trace_type_builder.py", line 
175, in <dictcomp>
        {k: from_value(value[k], context) for k in value}, mapping_type)
    File "C:\Users\giorg\OneDrive\Desktop\Trader Bot\venv\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\core\function\trace_type\trace_type_builder.py", line 144, in from_value
        elif isinstance(value, trace.SupportsTracingProtocol):
    File "C:\Users\giorg\OneDrive\Desktop\Trader Bot\venv\Lib\site-packages\typing_extensions.py", line 647, in __instancecheck__
        val = inspect.getattr_static(instance, attr)
    File "C:\Users\giorg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\inspect.py", line 1830, in getattr_static
        instance_result = _check_instance(obj, attr)
    File "C:\Users\giorg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\inspect.py", line 1777, in _check_instance
        instance_dict = object.__getattribute__(obj, "__dict__")

    TypeError: this __dict__ descriptor does not support '_DictWrapper' objects

I tried creating a custom driver like this:
    action_step = self._policy.action(time_step, policy_state)
    next_time_step = self._env.step(action_step.action)
    traj = trajectory.from_transition(time_step, action_step, next_time_step)

    for observer in self._observers:
        observer(traj)

If i simply run this in a for loop there is no problem, but when i try to run like:
while not time_step.is_last():
    ...

I get the same error. How can I fix this?
I don't know where the problem is, if is in the observation or in the driver.

I found where i was wrong. In my observation I was passing a nested dictionary. tf_agents doesn't support this feature.
